# Android source code for specific devices

Tags: android, git

1. Android source code has multiple directories with code for different devices. Also, within a particular directory, there are paths showing different branches and tags. Just as an example, within 'android / platform / external / iptables' directory (url: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/iptables/), we have multiple branches showing different releases - e.g. master, brillo, lollipop, marshmallow, etc. For each of them, there are different versions - marshmallow-cts-release, marshmallow-dev, marshmallow-dr-dev, marshmallow-dr-dragon-release, marshmallow-dr-release, marshmallow-dr1.5-dev, marshmallow-dr1.5-release, marshmallow-dr1.6-release, marshmallow-mr1-dev, marshmallow-mr1-release, marshmallow-mr2-release, marshmallow-mr3-release, marshmallow-release.

How do we identify which branch is implemented in a particular device? Also, there is an option to select tags - which also list various versions of say Android 7.1.1. If I am searching for source code of one phone (e.g. HTC 10), is there a way that I can identify the source code of that particular device?

2. Do the OEMs such as HTC, Samsung, Motorola, Xiaomi, Google etc. use the Android source code in the form that is available at Git repository (open source) or do they make some modifications in the source code for their devices? Further, if there are any modifications, is it possible to view the final source code used by OEMs?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!
Regards,
John

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of OEM Kernel Source Codes for You.

**LG**
http://www.lg.com/global/support/ope...opensource.jsp

- Under category select mobile phones and hit the search button located to the right, optionally you can enter in a model number to search for.

**HTC**
http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads

- You can easily find what you’re looking for by using the filters, for device, carrier, region, and android version. You will also find some useful files here besides kernel source code.

**Samsung**
http://opensource.samsung.com/index....7CE750C8AD80E1

- The easiest way to find your device is to use the search box and search for your devices model number.

**Motorola**
http://sourceforge.net/motorola/wiki/Projects/
https://github.com/MotorolaMobilityLLC

- Contains some devices kernel source code as well as many device specific proprietary files.

**Kyocera**
http://www.kyocera-wireless.com/support/developers.htm

- Small selection of kernel source code in addition to some other code.

**Sony (Ericsson)**
http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/xperia-open-source-archives/

- Variety of kernel sources and some interesting release notes documents

**Google**
https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML

- Very large selection of kernel sources for Google devices as well as tons of other hardware specific files.

**Pantech**
http://opensource.pantech.com/model/...ategory=Mobile

- You have to sign-up and create an account (Don’t worry it’s free and easy) before you can download the kernel sources. You can use the list on your left to quickly scroll through the available devices to find the one you are looking for.

**ZTE**
http://support.zte.com.cn/support/ne...x?type=service
http://support.zte.com.cn/support/Se...rviceMain.aspx

- Random of assortment of kernel sources, software updates, and pieces of code for ZTE devices. Note, the second link requires you to register for an account which gives you further access but requires you to wait a day of two for your account to be approved.

**Asus**
http://support.asus.com/download/opt...x?SLanguage=en

- You can either preform a model name search to find your device or press the select model manually and select if from the list. Common product model families for Android include Eee Pad (Select under Eee Family) and PadFone (In Handheld and Navigation, under Mobile Phone, then PadFone series). It includes everything from kernel source, firmware, USB drivers, and manuals.

**Acer**
http://support.acer.com/product/default.aspx

- Includes kernel source for some phones and tablets. To find your device click on the link that says select a product model if your device is a smartphone select smart handheld then select your device model. If your device is a tablet select tablet from the family of products list then select your device model.

**Archos**
http://www.archos.com/support/suppor...try=us&lang=en

- Includes the kernel source code for many of Archos tablets from several generations of products, as well as firmware and other experimental software for the tablet.

**Dell**
http://opensource.dell.com/releases/

- Kernel source for many of Dell's Android devices as well as some additional patches, and driver files.

**Huawei**
http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwid...&type=software
http://consumer.huawei.com/en/suppor...oads/index.htm

- Kernel source for many of Huawei's devices both phones and tablets, also includes platform code, firmware, and some user manuals, you can scroll through the available software by hitting the *more* button at the bottom of the page

**Alcatel**
http://sourceforge.net/projects/alca...?source=navbar

- Kernel source as well as other files for development of Alcatel branded devices

**Other Resources**

**Qualcomm**
https://www.codeaurora.org/xwiki/bin/QAEP/
https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/

- Great resource for finding the kernel source code of many Qualcomm chipsets.

**Amlogic**
http://openlinux.amlogic.com/index.php/Arm/Kernel_Info

PS: Original Thread Found on  [XDA Dev Group](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1808167)

Comment: Thank you for sharing the sources. I am concerned whether these are source code components related only to kernel? For example, in Android Git repository, there are some directories for kernel, and others for platform, hardware, packages, etc. Is it correct to say that the code provided at individual OEM websites is only related to kernel, and the rest of the android source code is used as it is in Google Git repositories?

Comment: Although, after downloading the Samsung code for SM-G960U1, it doesn't contain any Java files.